# Google Sheets: Search Multiple Sheets, Return Related Value

Tags: google-sheets, match, vlookup, lookup

I'm attempting to write a formula to search multiple sheets for an Inventory number (stored in Column G of 1 of 2 spreadsheets), then return the related item name (stored in the corresponding A Column.) Some Inventory numbers are either 'Listed for Sale' or 'Sold', so they are either on the "Listed" spreadsheet or "Sold" or both (as I do have duplicates of some items.)

My problem is that F911 (the cell where the inventory number is stored) is text and the value I want returned is text.  So, if I just use Lookup, it returns an item name based on the most similar inventory number without ever looking at the "Sold" sheet, because it can't find it within the "Listed" sheet and doesn't throw an error:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(F911,'Listed Inventory'!G:G,'Listed Inventory'!A:A),LOOKUP(F911,'Sold Inventory'!G:G,'Sold Inventory'!A:A))
```

So, I tried using `MATCH` to force an error on the first sheet (Listed) and return a value for the second (Sold):

```
=IFERROR((MATCH(F911,'Listed Inventory'!G:G,0),LOOKUP(F911,'Listed Inventory'!G:G,'Listed Inventory'!A:A)),LOOKUP(F911,'Sold Inventory'!G:G,'Sold Inventory'!A:A))
```

But this just gives a formula parse error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the ranges with `{` and `}` and do a simple INDEX MATCH withouy any error fallback just to check another sheet.

```
=INDEX({'Listed Inventory'!A:A; 'Sold Inventory'!A:A}, 
       MATCH(F911, {'Listed Inventory'!G:G; 'Sold Inventory'!G:G}, 0))
```